# InverseWaveletTransform of a list of rules

Tags: wavelet-analysis

I want to extract coefficient images from a `DiscreteWaveletTransform` and replace them by modified images of the same dimensions.

However,  when I use `DiscreteWaveletData` without specifying the input image dimensions the dimension of the `InverseWaveletTransform` result is halved, and when I explicitly specify the type of wavelet (`HaarWavelet`) and transform (`DiscreteWaveletTransform`) used in the original forward transform the result of `InverseWaveletTransform` has the right dimensions, but looks quite different from the original input image.

What am I doing wrong?

```
im = Import["ExampleData\lena.tif"];
dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[im, Automatic, 1];
inrules = dwd[All, {"Image"}];
```

[image]

```
{rec1, rec2, rec3} = 
    InverseWaveletTransform[#] & /@ {dwd, DiscreteWaveletData[inrules], 
    DiscreteWaveletData[inrules, HaarWavelet[], "DiscreteWaveletTransform"]}
```

[image]

```
ImageDimensions[#] & /@ {rec1, rec2, rec3}
{{150, 116}, {75, 58}, {150, 116}}
```

Comment: I am searching for a solution to this problem, but can't you just use `WaveletMapIndexed` and try to work from there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the last problem is caused by the standard behavior of the "Image" option. By default, it seems that the resulting output images are color adjusted (for optimal visibility?).

```
inrules = dwd[All, {"Image"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use `"ImageFunction" -> Identity` to prevent this:

```
inrules = dwd[All, {"Image", "ImageFunction" -> Identity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with an inverse transform of:

```
InverseWaveletTransform[
    DiscreteWaveletData[inrules, HaarWavelet[],"DiscreteWaveletTransform"]
]
```

[image]

(see "Scope/Get coefficients" section of the `DiscreteWaveletData` documentation page)

As to your first problem, I can only guess. The specification `DiscreteWaveletData[inrules]` you used (with only the rules in place) is not listed as a possible syntax in the syntax box of the `DiscreteWaveletData` doc page, so one could say you're lucky you get any output at all. To construct a fully inverse-transformable object you're apparently supposed to use:

```
DiscreteWaveletData[Normal[dwd], dwd["Wavelet"], dwd["Transform"], dwd["DataDimensions"]]
```

(see "Properties & Relations" section of the `DiscreteWaveletData` documentation page).

Comment: @lex BTW, welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange!

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd, you're right on both accounts!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think there is nothing wrong with the current behavior. I think if you want to keep the size of the images you should keep the data. In order to do that you should use '*StationaryWaveletTransform*' rather than '*DiscreteWaveletTransform*'. So, below the code works...

```
im = Import["ExampleData\\lena.tif"];
swt = StationaryWaveletTransform[im, Automatic, 1]
inrules = swt [All, {"Image"}]
```

> [image]

```
{rec1, rec2, rec3} = 
 InverseWaveletTransform[#] & /@ {swt, DiscreteWaveletData[inrules], 
   DiscreteWaveletData[inrules, HaarWavelet[], 
    "StationaryWaveletTransform"]}
ImageDimensions[#] & /@ {rec1, rec2, rec3}
```

> [image]
>
> {{150, 116}, {150, 116}, {150, 116}}